# Formato mensajes validacion de formulario laravel, vuejs y axios

Tags: php, bootstrap, vue.js, axios

Tengo el siguiente problema con el formato de los mensajes de errores de formulario en **laravel**, el cual uso **vuejs** con la libreria **axios** para capturarlos y enviarlo a la vista.

Cuando quiero mostrar el mensaje funciona bien, pero lo esta mostrando de la siguiente forma:

> [ "El campo rut es requerido." ]

y quiero que quede asi.

> El campo rut es requerido.

He buscado usar substring sin resultado.
El script:

```
}).catch(error => {
    toastr.error('Hubo un error al guardar ');
    this.errors.push(error.response.data.errors.rut);
})
```

y el template:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" v-if="errors.length">
     <b>Por favor corriga los siguientes errores:</b>
     <ul>
         <li v-for="error in errors">{{ error }}</li>
     </ul>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Indicar que todo aquello esta dentro de un componente de **vuejs**

favor de su ayuda.

saludos

Comment: pero cual seria el problema?

Comment: Actualizado, sorry.

Comment: Intenta en el this.error.push hacer this.errors.push(error.response.data.errors.rut.shift()); o has un for y ve insertando todo lo que tenga rut pk es un arreglo

Comment: Gracias Dariel Ramos, me funciono.

Answer (score 0):

Prácticamente el acceder de esta manera

```
<li v-for="error in errors">{{ error[0] }}</li>
```

No estoy seguro si funciona en general pero para cada inputs sería de esta manera para input name

```
<li v-for="error in errors">{{ error.name[0] }}</li>
```